# Does GitHub have an endpoint for reading a users GPG keys?

Tags: gnupg, github

Github produces a nice HTTP endpoint to read a users RSA keys. Do they have something like this for GPG keys (without needing additional auth or through the developer API)? If not why and/or when will it be available?

An example of the GitHub users RSA keys: https://github.com/cmcginty.keys

Comment: If a specific feature is available or not at a third party site and when it will be available is a question you have to ask the third party  instead of asking it here.

Comment: There is -- recently, there was a question about using the API: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46042009/695343